# Replace non-null values with blank or null values in SQL oracle SELECT query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm basically trying to write a query where if an event occurs within the last 200 days, it will display column values for A, B, C, D, E, F
But in this same query, if an event does not occur within the last 200 days (201 days & beyond), it will only display values in columns A and B.

My current query I tried to do two select statements using the UNION statement. I tried to do a CASE statements for column C, D, E and F for the SELECT after the UNION, but I could not get it to work.

This current query displays all values for all columns regardless of if it occurred < or > 200 days.

```html
SELECT  te.columna,
     c.columnb,
     te.columnc,
     v.columnd,
    v.columne,
    v.columnf
 FROM table1 te, table2 c, table3 v
     WHERE te.columng_id=c.columng_id
    AND v.columne=te.columne
    AND te.columnc > sysdate-200
  UNION
     SELECT te.columna,
     c.columnb,
    te.columnc,
    v.columnd,
    v.columne,
    v.columnf
     FROM table1 te, table2 c, table3 v
    WHERE te.columng_id=c.columng_id
    AND v.columne=te.columne
    AND te.columnc < sysdate-200
```

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? They're not the same.

Comment: Oracle, sorry. I'm new to the whole SQL thing so I keep forgetting which one is which. I'm using SQL Plus to do this query right now.

Comment: I have to note that with using `te.columnc > sysdate-200` and `te.columnc < sysdate-200` you're missing a potential value. It probably won't affect the query at all but one of those operators should be "or equal to". That is, you can use "greater than" (`>`) together with "less than or equal to" (`<=`) or "less than" (`<`) with "greater than or equal to" (`>=`). You might also want to use the `TRUNC()` function to truncate the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `CASE` in `Oracle` -

```
 SELECT  te.columna,
          c.columnb,
          CASE WHEN te.columnc >= SYSDATE -200
           THEN te.columnc
           ELSE NULL
        END columnc,
        CASE WHEN te.columnc >= SYSDATE -200
           THEN te.columnd
           ELSE NULL
        END columnd,
        CASE WHEN te.columnc >= SYSDATE -200
           THEN v.columne
           ELSE NULL
        END columne,
        CASE WHEN te.columnc >= SYSDATE -200
           THEN v.columnf
           END columnf
    FROM    table1 te, table2 c, table3 v
        WHERE te.columng_id=c.columng_id
    AND v.columne=te.columne
```

Comment: This works like wonder! Thank you so much, I guess I didn't realize I had to keep repeating the column name and the >= SYSDATE for every separate column.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. And you could safely avoid the UNION statement. Please mark it as answered :-)